# Create a dynamic array of class objects inside a class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am having trouble creating a dynamic array of class objects inside a class in C++. The concept is: assume we have a class A. In this class, I want to have an array of objects with the same type of class (eg. A* array), whose memory will be allocated dynamically (we don't know the size of this array at the beginning). In `main()` I want to create an array of 2 objects. The first will have an array with 3 elements of class A, and the second object with 6 elements. So, every object will have its own array. Here are my thoughts:

Basic concept:

```
|_|_|_| //Array with 3 elements of class A in object A

 |   _____  |_|_|_|_|_|_| //Array with 6 elements of class A in object B
 |  |
|A||B| //Basic array with 2 elements
```

```
class A {
    A* array;
  public:
    A(int k) {
      //array = new A[k]; //this doesn't work because it calls the default constructor.
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
        array = new A(k); //This doesn't work either.
      cout << "A created." << endl;
    };
    ~A() {
      cout << "Destroying A!" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
  A *ar[2];
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
      ar[i] = new A(3);
    } else {
      ar[i] = new A(6);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `std::vector` period!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Vectors is the best implementation but this is a project in which i am not allowed to use them.

Comment: `std::vector` wouldn't solve the infinite recursion problem. Where do you stop the nesting?

Comment: @Vkt678 What a pity (silly restictions). Then I'll advise to study the available implementations of `std::vector` and mimic your own based upon that.

Comment: So why is `class A` containing instances of itself?  Maybe you need separate the concept of container from object.

Answer (score 1):

You should use std::vector, but if you must use arrays, the syntax to dynamically declare one is

```
type * name = new type[size];
```

So you would do

```
A * arr = new A[k];
```

Size would be a variable that you have, and you'd have to resize the array each time it needed to grow, by making your own grow() function which is a huge pain. Just use vectors!

EDIT: Your program is also loaded iwth memory leaks. Vectors habdle these automatically but every time you use new to create an array, you must delete that array with

```
delete [] name;
```